# Trimming new line character from a string in bash

Tags: excel, bash, csv, sed

I am pulling data from a .csv file exported from excel.

the csv file looks like this:

```
Category,Feature,Description,app1,app2,app3,app4,app5,app6,app7
Employee Relations,Employee Management,,y,y,n,y,y,y,n
Employee Relations,Employee Availability,,y,y,n,n,y,y,n
```

the problem is the end character line feed is getting in the way. take the following code:

```
title=$(head -n 1 $1) # grab the first row
title=`echo $title | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/ *$//'` # me trying to fix. I think this is the issue
echo $title  #this seems to look right
IFS=',' read -a titline <<<"$title"   # make it an array

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#titline[@]} ; i++ )) do
    echo "[[${titline[$i]}]]"
done
```

prints out:

```
Category,Feature,Description,app1,app2,app3,app4,app5,app6,app7
[[Category]]
[[Feature]]
[[Description]]
[[app1]]
[[app2]]
[[app3]]
[[app4]]
[[app5]]
[[app6]]
]]app7
```

as you can see the last line should be:

```
[[app7]]
```

and this is screwing with the rest of the script.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and can use a pointer

Comment: what does your script do? your ultimate goal? I feel awk would be better way to deal with csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your csv file has DOS line endings.

I copied and pasted your data and your script and it produces the output:

```
Category,Feature,Description,app1,app2,app3,app4,app5,app6,app7
[[Category]]
[[Feature]]
[[Description]]
[[app1]]
[[app2]]
[[app3]]
[[app4]]
[[app5]]
[[app6]]
[[app7]]
```

I then converted the csv file to DOS line-endings and got the same issue that you saw.

The solution is to use `dos2unix` or similar utility to fix the file before you read from it.  This can be done as follows:

```
title=$(dos2unix <"$1" | head -n 1) # grab the first row
echo $title
IFS=',' read -a titline <<<"$title"   # make it an array
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#titline[@]} ; i++ )) do
    echo "[[${titline[$i]}]]"
done
```

Or, you can use `sed`:

```
title=$(head -n 1 "$1" | sed 's/\r//') # grab the first row
echo $title
IFS=',' read -a titline <<<"$title"   # make it an array
for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#titline[@]} ; i++ )) do
    echo "[[${titline[$i]}]]"
done
```